# Suddenly can't bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler, gemset

I haven't changed the versions numbers on any of these since it was working, but suddenly when I run `bundle update` or `bundle install` I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.1) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.0.1) ruby

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.1.1)
```

What changed and what gives?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that sass-rails is will accept railties 4.0.1, rails will not accept railties 4.1.1.  The solution was to call out sass-rails with an explicit version number at the beggining of the Gemfile.

Before:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

After:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'railties', '4.0.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```